# Is there a library to compare primitive type values?

Tags: java, compareto

I am implementing `Comparable` interface on a trivial class that wraps a single `int` member.

I can implement it this way:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo ( final MyType o )
    {
        return
            Integer.valueOf( this.intVal ).compareTo(
                Integer.valueOf( o.intVal )
            );
    }
```

But this (maybe) creates 2 totally unnecessary Integer objects.

Or I can go tried and true cut-and-paste approach from Integer class:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo ( final MyType o )
    {
      int thisVal = this.intValue;
      int anotherVal = o.intValue;
      return (thisVal<anotherVal ? -1 : (thisVal==anotherVal ? 0 : 1));
    }
```

This is pretty efficient, but duplicates code unnecessary.

Is there a library that would implement this missing `Integer` ( and Double and Float ) method?

```
   public static int compare ( int v1, int v2 );
```

Comment: Could you copy the Integer `compareTo()` to a new method that takes two arguments instead of using `this`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 7, `static int compare` for primitive types have been added to all primitive object wrapper classes, i.e there is now:

```
java.lang.Integer: static int compare( int x, int y );
java.lang.Byte: static int compare( byte x, byte y );
java.lang.Short: static int compare( short x, short y );
etc...
```

Answer (score 6):

- For `int`, write your own `compare` method (it requires at most three lines of
  code).
- For `double`, use [`Double.compare`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29) (not to be confused with
  `compareTo`).
- For `float`, use [`Float.compare`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare%28float,%20float%29).

The last two take primitive types and thus avoid boxing and unboxing. I can see an argument for `Integer` providing a similar `compare` method, but as things stand it doesn't.

Comment: `Integer` also has a `compare`

Comment: @Steve Kuo: Link to Javadoc please?

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking of `compareTo`, in which case he could do `Integer.valueOf(i1).compareTo(i2)`.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: No, it doesn't, that's the point. And, by the way, if you've read the question I know how to do `Integer.valueOf`

Comment: +1: For byte, short, int and float you can use Double.compare().

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, I'm missing something, but IMHO this is a weird question.

> Is there a library that would implement this missing `Integer` ( and
>   Double and Float ) method?
>
> ```
> public static int compare ( int v1, int v2 );
> ```

Well, I think this does the job:

```
public static int compare ( int v1, int v2 )
{
    if (v1 < v2) return -1;
    if (v1 > v2) return  1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @barjak: Nope, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273091/is-there-a-library-to-compare-primitive-type-values/7273222#7273222 and it comments.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is simple, but perhaps simplistic:

```
public static int compare ( int v1, int v2 )
{
    return v1 - v2;
}
```

Note: @aix is correct! This approach will not work for arbitrary integers. It will work for always-positive integers though, for example auto generated database keys etc

Comment: How about integer overflow?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux, you are incorrect, `compare` and `compareTo` specify negative, 0, positive values. It doesn't dictate -1, 0 1. Any code that checks for -1 is bad and broken code. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29

Comment: No, the Javadoc says "negative, zero or positive", for both Comparable and Integer.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: Oops, indeed! Thanks, I learnt something today :D